# error while loading shared libraries: libgvc.so.6 (deploy django app on heroku)

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, graphviz, buildpack

I have a problem with a heroku deployment because I have an application with multiple buildpacks  that use python, r, scikitlearn and grahpviz buildpacks. The application deployed corretly, but when I try to see trees that are made by graphviz I have this problem:

***"Program terminated with status: 127. stderr follows: /app/.heroku-buildpack-graphviz/usr/bin/dot: error while loading shared libraries: libgvc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"***

I know that all graphviz dependeces are installed correctly but in this directory "/app/.heroku-buildpack-graphviz/usr/lib" I tried to move it but does not work. Also I use heroku-16 because I read that graphviz buildpack not work in heroku-18.

Could anybody help me?